# Fetching the data from sqlite3 database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I need some help with my PHP. I have a trouble with fetching the data from the database. I have hired a PHP developer who did not do his job properly that he have messed up the code which make it don't work so I need some help to fix the issue to get it working again.

When I try this:

```
//open the database File
$db = new SQLite3('myChannel.db');

if(!$db) 
{
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} 
else 
{
   $channel_name = $_GET['channels'];

   $sql ="SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date, description FROM programs WHERE channel='$channel_name'";

   $results = $db->query($sql);

   while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) 
   {
     print_r($row);
   }
```

What happen with the code is it will not fetching the matched data from the database as it will not do anything. I think there is something wrong with the $sql variable.

What I'm expecting to do is I want to look for data in the database where I use the variable called `$channel_name`, then I want to fetch the matched data to output them in my PHP.

Can you please help me how I can fetch the matched data in the database?

Comment: Is this `myChannel.db` file in the same directory as the running code?

Comment: what is showing in your print_r()? is it showing some data or empty?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes it is

Comment: @rowmoin it is showing nothing in print_r when i try it

Comment: In your database, the value exists what you are passing when you are trying to test?

Comment: @rowmoin yes it is

Comment: Could you please run this code //open the database File
$db = new SQLite3('myChannel.db');

if(!$db) 
{
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} 
else 
{
   $channel_name = $_GET['channels'];

  echo $sql ="SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date, description FROM programs WHERE channel='$channel_name'";
die();
   $results = $db->query($sql);

   while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) 
   {
     print_r($row);
   } and see what query return

Comment: after return a query please run this query in your database GUI

Comment: @rowmoin here is the return `SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date, description FROM programs WHERE channel='BBC One S East'`

Comment: run this statement query in your database gui

Comment: when I try this: `$sql ="SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date, description from programs where channel='$channel_name'"; $ret = $db->query($sql);


        $row1 = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
        echo $row1;` I get this `BBC One S Eaststring(98) "SELECT channel,title,start_date,stop_date,description FROM programs WHERE channel='BBC One S East'"`

Comment: so you get your data.

Comment: i think everything is fine

Comment: also you can set those top of your page even any error showing in your code: ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

Comment: @rowmoin well when I use `print_r($row);` under the `while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) {` it will not show anything. do you know why?

Comment: could you please use ver_dump($row) and see what happen

Comment: when i try this: `$sql = "SELECT channel,title,start_date,stop_date,description FROM programs WHERE channel='$channel_name'";
          $results = $db->query($sql); var_dump($results);` I will get this `object(SQLite3Result)#3 (0) { }`

Comment: why you ver_dump($results). you should replacing that print_r($row)

Comment: while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) { var_dump($row);}

Comment: it still show this `SQLite3Result Object ( )`

Comment: I have tried this `while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) { var_dump($row);}` it still show nothing. :(

Comment: //open the database File
$db = new SQLite3('myChannel.db');

if(!$db) 
{
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} 
else 
{
   $channel_name = $_GET['channels'];

   $sql ="SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date, description FROM programs WHERE channel='$channel_name'";

   $results = $db->query($sql);
    $data = array();
   while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) 
   {
     $data[]=$row;
   }
   
   var_dump($data);

Comment: Try  this code and see what happen

Comment: I know why, I am using sqlite3 database to fetch the data as I must use `$sql ="SELECT * from programs where channel LIKE'%$channel_name%'";` to fetch the data I want so it works fine :)

Comment: do you know why using LIKE? The LIKE clause to fetch data from a MySQL table. You can specify any condition using the WHERE clause. so its depends on you what you want to show you want to show exact matching data or some match data field

Comment: when you are using LIKE then you are getting couple of data more than one that is why you are getting data in your while loop but when in your where condition in your database that return just one

Comment: "I have hired a PHP developer who did not do his job properly that he have messed up the code which make it don't work so I need some help to fix the issue to get it working again." If you use version control, like git, then you simply rewind to the last good commit and you're done. This code (and the current answer) are open to SQL injection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code based on the [SQLite PHP docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm)

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
        $this->open('myChannel.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if (!$db) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    $channel_name = $_GET['channels'];
    $sql = "SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date, description FROM programs WHERE channel='{$channel_name}'";
    $results = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

I changed a few things. I turned your database connection into a class, and I changed your while to include `SQLITE3_ASSOC`.

> Warning: OP's code and as a result this answer has code that is
>   vulnerable to SQL Injection!

Comment: @grumptycrouton you dont need the class MYDB function, you can use something is like `$channel_name = $_GET['channels'];` so the code you wrote is bad...

Comment: @RobertJones The thing you wrote has nothing to do with the database connection. I didn't change the way `$channel_name` was set. All I did was change the way the database is handled, based on the docs that I linked to, which I know works because I use it in a lot of applications.

Comment: You did not fix the SQL injection.

Comment: @CL. I wasn't attempting to, that's not part of the question. It's not my job to fix OP's security holes.